# Using NAudio getcapabilities to identify a specific microphone input

Tags: windows, audio, naudio

I am using NAudio to monitor microphone input on Windows 7 workstations.  I need to monitor a specific microphone input.  When the program detects an audible signal on the input it triggers a process to run.  I store the microphone device name in a configuration file.  When my program starts up it looks for the device by matching the stored name against the values reported by GetCapabilities:

```
Public Function findAudioinDeviceId(deviceName As String) As Integer

Dim deviceCount As Integer = NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount

Dim i As Integer
Dim d As NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities

For i = 0 To deviceCount - 1
  d = NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i)
  If d.ProductName = deviceName Then
    Return i
  End If
Next

Return -1

End Function
```

This all works great.  However, the other day a user reported that the mic monitor stopped working.  I noticed that on the users workstation the device name NAudio reports was different than the stored device name.

The device in question is a USB audio adapter - it connects microphone in to the workstation via USB connection.  I noticed that as I plug the adapter into different USB ports the sequence number is added/incremented in the device name:

- 1st USB Port: Microphone (Logitech G430 Gamin
- 2nd USB Port: Microphone (2- Logitech G430 Ga
- 3rd USB Port: Microphone (3- Logitech G430 Ga
- ...etc...

Does anyone know of a reliable way to reference audio devices with NAudio?  Note that I will have 20 or more customer installations with identical hardware setup.  I'd like to be able to set the device name at program installation time.  I'd also like to avoid telling customers to be sure to always use the same USB port.

Comment: Can you store the manufacturer and product id instead of the product name? Another alternative is to read (via p/invoke) the WAVEINCAPS2 structure which has extra guids.

Comment: Hmmm, I will do some checking.

Comment: I assume you mean the product and manufacturer guids?  They are properties of the WaveInCapabilities object returned by GetCapabilities.  I am not sure those will necessarily identify unique inputs.  On my laptop and docking station, for example, I have three microphone in ports - one on the docking station, the external jack built into the laptop, and the internal mic.  They all report the same product and manufacturer guids.  I am  thinking I may use a regular expression in my configuration file and test that against the product name.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I guess it's laziness on the part of the mic manufacturers that they are all returning the same info. They must all be using the same drivers and chip-set.